# <PBXResourcesBuildPhase UUID=..> attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID

Tags: xcode, svn, cocoapods, xcode7.2

I have taken SVN check-in for a project. Thereafter I have installed pod via *terminal*. After installation of pod there are few warning stating

```
    <PBXResourcesBuildPhase UUID=...> attempted to initialise an 
    object with an unknown UUID.
```

[image: Screenshot for warning]
What might be reason? **Is this warning critical**?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The reason that happened in my case was some developer updated a pod A while I installed a new pod B (without updated pod A). So when I merged his codes I got the warning.

An easy way to fix this is to

```
1. remove libPods.a from General->Linked Frameworks and libraries 
2. run `pod install` or `pod update "an-existing-pod"` again.
```

For step #2 the purpose is to update .xcodeproj file not to install pod again. If pod is already there cocoapods will just update .xcodeproj file.

Answer (score 70):

**`Step 1:`**
Deintegrate your project from CocoaPods. Removing all traces of CocoaPods from your Xcode project.

$`pod deintegrate ProjectName.XCODEPROJ`

**`Step 2:`**
Install the pod Again

$`pod install`

**Make sure you are replacing ProjectName.XCODEPROJ with your project name.**

Comment: This worked for me and was significantly easier than messing around with linked frameworks and libraries.

Comment: This is the right way to make CocoaPods regenerate the project. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 39):

**Xcode 8 - 14**

Target > General > Linked Frameworks and Libraries

[image: PBXResourcesBuildPhase]

Comment: After much brainstorming, this fix worked for me!! The pod project file does not have any errors now.

Comment: Also fixed the issue for me. Xcode automatically adds the Pods back to the Linked Frameworks and Libraries, so deleting it purely fixed the pod warning for me.

Answer (score 6):

The way I solved that is not described in the thread

- Commented all pods and run `pod install`. `Pods` folder eventually removed. But still having the warning in the `terminal`
- Uncommented the pod. re-run `pod install`. The warning is now gone.

Answer (score 4):

This error happened to me after resolving some merge conflicts in the project file.

In Xcode 11.4.1, I removed `Pods_TARGETNAME.framework` under Project Settings > General > Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content.

I then ran `pod install`, after which everything was fine again.

Answer (score 3):

It still happens from time to time to me. My solution is to search after the unknown UUID in your project file and simply delete all lines you'll find.

Terminal-command:

```
cat YOUR_PROCJECT_NAME.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj | grep 'UNKNOWN_UUID'
```

You should find something like this:

```
UNKNOWN_UUID /* (null) in Resources */,
```

Comment: This was my fix. A file had been removed from the project, but a stray reference was still in the project.pbxproj. Manually deleted the line

Answer (score 3):

My colleague and I spent hours trying to figure out how to fix a similar error:

> [!] `<PBXBuildFile UUID=`050DCB84CE258104B4E8C808`>` attempted to
> initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `12B87A081D0745C6D77F7885`
> for attribute: `file_ref`. This can be the result of a merge and the
> unknown UUID is being discarded.

What fixed it for us:

1. identify the file that the "unknown UUID" referred to, in the .pbxproj file; in our case, it was `libPods-<TARGET_NAME>.a`
2. find that file in the file browser in XCode
3. delete the file within XCode
4. rerun `pod install`

Answer (score 2):

Just run

`pod clean 
 pod install`.

And those errors should go.

Comment: Using Cocoapods 1.10.1 it says `[!] Unknown command: clean`; how do you have this command ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you fixed this or not, but for future reference, I has the same issue.

On my case, after opening *.pbxproj* file on a text editor, realised that the first UUID pointed to the *'Copy Bundle Resources'* of the *'Build Phases'*.

Removing that and adding again fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I commented out all pods and did "pod install" then uncommented all pods to previous state and did "pod install". That solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

Open xprj file in ordinary editor and find file with your UID = "C39D10ED1BD5F1F0000C4DD9". In my case file does not exist and left from merge process

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I re-run `pod install` and find this warnings aren't showing. This is due to merging the project file.

Answer (score 0):

There could also be problem with multiple xcode version installations. Try this link for more details -

https://www.ryadel.com/en/xcode-sdk-iphoneos-cannot-be-located-mac-osx-error-fix/

Comment: Nope...this problem has got nothing to do with multiple versions of Xcode.