# Getting error when installing phonegap-plugin-push on iOS for Ionic 2 project

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic2, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to install "phonegap-plugin-push" for iOS in Ionic 2 project but getting following errors:

```
[!] `<PBXSourcesBuildPhase UUID=`1D60588E0D05DD3D006BFB54`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `7EC8547169A74BD5A8A5460B` for attribute: `files`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.

[!] `<PBXSourcesBuildPhase UUID=`1D60588E0D05DD3D006BFB54`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `A681F5B62F934658A6DEC23E` for attribute: `files`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.

[!] `<PBXSourcesBuildPhase UUID=`1D60588E0D05DD3D006BFB54`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `E23C540A0DA14793BE17F093` for attribute: `files`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.

[!] `<PBXSourcesBuildPhase UUID=`1D60588E0D05DD3D006BFB54`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `1AC97AB1822E4E15997E168E` for attribute: `files`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.

[!] `<PBXSourcesBuildPhase UUID=`1D60588E0D05DD3D006BFB54`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `AE2A50F808434C37B9584D53` for attribute: `files`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.

[!] `<PBXSourcesBuildPhase UUID=`1D60588E0D05DD3D006BFB54`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `EB49FF87CB794718B96280A7` for attribute: `files`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.

[!] `<PBXSourcesBuildPhase UUID=`1D60588E0D05DD3D006BFB54`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `998B570BB91F4A0FB8D4B663` for attribute: `files`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.

[!] `<PBXSourcesBuildPhase UUID=`1D60588E0D05DD3D006BFB54`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `8562C2D8B88748C69F022169` for attribute: `files`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.

[!] `<PBXSourcesBuildPhase UUID=`1D60588E0D05DD3D006BFB54`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `F07DC83F4D744CFB8600CBAF` for attribute: `files`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.

[!] `<PBXSourcesBuildPhase UUID=`1D60588E0D05DD3D006BFB54`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `4C4252986B454BB2AEA5BEAA` for attribute: `files`. This can be the result of a merge and  the unknown UUID is being discarded.
```

Comment: it may not be related to the plugin.. check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36597286/pbxresourcesbuildphase-uuid-attempted-to-initialize-an-object-with-an-unkno)

Comment: I am new to iOS development, not able to find General->Linked Frameworks and libraries. Please help

Comment: are you able to open the project in xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed it for me https://geek-is-stupid.github.io/2015-11-17-cocoapods-install-rase-warnings-this-can-be-the-result-of-a-merge-and-the-unknown-uuid-is-being-discarded/

Summary:

Remove the plugin, go to Xcode, click any file, open the inspector on right hand side, click the "target" checkbox, click it again, then retry adding the plugin.